# "Se morrer, morreu" em inglês?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Um jeito informal de designar um certo conformismo estoico em relação a algo que normalmente é entendido como doloroso ou ruim é expressar um verbo no subjuntivo e em seguida no pretérito perfeito. Por exemplo:

> — Não quero aprender a andar de bicicleta. Posso cair e me machucar.
> — Ora, tente! **Se machucar, machucou**, faz parte. Do chão lhe garanto que não passa.

De que forma poderia expressar o mesmo em inglês?

Comment: Eu não vejo problema em “if you die, you die(d). What is the issue?”. Será interessante ver a tradução da @Lambie.

Comment: O uso do pretérito perfeito aqui me confunde, porque aparentemente fala do futuro. Tem o sentido de "já aconteceu, já é feito"?

Comment: @DanGetz, depois da vírgula, a frase está no futuro, então, "morreu" seria "terá morrido" no presente. Como em "amanhã eu faço isso", "eu faço isso" está no amanhã. Talvez esteja errado, mas essa sempre foi a sensação que tive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sugestão do Schilive, **if you die you die**, é de fato uma boa opção. Encontrei [registro de Jeremy Clarkson (britânico) a usando](https://www.theguardian.com/media/2021/aug/03/jeremy-clarkson-criticises-covid-scientists-saying-if-you-die-you-die) para expressar o sentido desejado:

> [About the pandemic] Or it could be for ever. “Well, if it’s going to be for ever, let’s open it up and **if you die, you die**.”

Também diz Ivan Drago, personagem fictício do filme Rocky IV, logo após um golpe que acaba por matar seu oponente Apollo,

> **If he dies, he dies**.

Answer (score 1):

Na realidade a expressão "*if he dies, he dies*" é mais sobre responsabilidade, não sobre conformismo. É usada idiomaticamente para qualquer situação, não apenas relacionada a "morte".

No Brasil, não usamos "se morrer, morreu" quando não há de fato um perigo eminente na situação, já a expressão em inglês pode entrar em diversos contextos, como duas pessoas conversando sobre alguém que tem que fazer algo de grande responsabilidade mas não está fazendo e pode se complicar por aquilo, então a segunda pessoa pode dizer "well, if he dies, he dies", mostrando que é a responsabilidade não é dele e ele não se importa com isso.

Comment: Fontesj, interessante a tua resposta. Terias alguma fonte para confirmar isso? Ou serias falante nativo?

Comment: Olá @Schilive! Sou Brasileiro Nativo. Qual das informações você gostaria de confirmar ou ter mais detalhes?

Comment: Fontesj, do sentido mais amplo que deste, em "[...] é mais sobre responsabilidade, não sobre conformismo. **É usada idiomaticamente para qualquer situação, não apenas relacionada a 'morte'**". Eu disse "fonte", mas pode ser, por exemplo, alguém falando em um vídeo, filme ou livro. Apenas algum tipo de confirmação.